# different way to write a method

Tags: c++, differential-equations

I have a class to define a right hand side terms of differential equation: 
this class provide the method to compute the rhs function and its derivate 
the function is store in a vector container in this way the class is suitable for the system of Differential Equation as well.

here the interface in which the method that I would to change is defined

```
 template <typename Type = double>
class rhsODEProblem {

       using analysisFunction = std::function<const Type(const Type, const std::valarray<Type>)>;


   public:



   rhsODEProblem(const std::vector<std::function<const Type(const Type,const std::valarray<Type>)>> numfun ,
                  const std::vector<std::function<const Type(const Type,const Type)>> exactfun ,
                  const Type,const Type,const Type,const std::valarray<Type>,const std::string ) noexcept ;


   rhsODEProblem(const std::vector<std::function<const Type(const Type,const std::valarray<Type>)>> numfun,
                 const Type, const Type, const Type, const std::valarray<Type> ) noexcept ;


      virtual ~rhsODEProblem() = default ;

      rhsODEProblem(const rhsODEProblem &) = default ;
      rhsODEProblem(rhsODEProblem&& ) = default ;
      rhsODEProblem& operator=(const rhsODEProblem&) = default ;
      rhsODEProblem& operator=(rhsODEProblem&& ) = default ;


      const std::vector<std::function<const Type(const Type,const std::valarray<Type>)>> numericalFunction ;

      const std::vector<std::function<const Type(const Type,const Type)>> analiticalFunction ;


      const std::vector<analysisFunction>&  f = numericalFunction ;   


      const auto dfdt(std::size_t indx , const Type t , const std::valarray<Type> u) {
            return (f[indx](t, u+eps )-f[indx](t,u))/eps ;
      }   


      auto setRhs (const std::vector<
                   std::function<const Type(const Type,const std::valarray<Type>)>> numfun) noexcept
      {     

        for(auto i=0 ; i < numfun.size() ; i++)
        {
          numericalFunction.push_back(numfun.at(i)) ; 
        }  
      } 

      auto setExact(const std::vector<std::function<const Type(const Type,const Type)>> exactfun) noexcept
      {
          for(auto i=0 ; i < exactfun.size(); i++)
          {
            analiticalFunction.push_back(exactfun.at(i));
          }  
      }

      auto solveExact() noexcept ;

      const Type t0() const noexcept { return _t0 ;} 
      const Type tf() const noexcept { return _tf ;}
      const Type dt() const noexcept { return _dt ;}
      const std::valarray<Type> u0() const noexcept { return _u0 ;}
      const std::string fname ()     const noexcept { return filename ;}


//---
   private:

                   Type  _t0 ;  // start time
                   Type  _tf ;  // final time
                   Type  _dt ;  // time-step
     std::valarray<Type> _u0 ;  // iv

     std::string filename ; 

     Type eps  = 1e-12  ; 


};
```

I would like to change the method dfdt in a way in which I can call it using the following syntax `dfdt[index]( t , u_valarray )` instead of `dfdt(index, t, u_valarray )` 
In which way I can change this method ?

**EDIT** thank for your answer so in my case it gonna be :

```
foo_helper(foo &, int index);
          operator()(int n, Type t, std::valarray<Type> u );
```

right ?

**EDIT** no I didn't get the point. I wrote :

```
class dfdx {
        public:
            dfdx( rhsODEProblem<Type> &r , int index_ ) : index{index_ } {}
            void operator()(Type t, std::valarray<Type> u){
                    return (f[index](t, u + eps )-f[index](t,u))/eps ;
            }
        int index ;
  };

  dfdx operator[](std::size_t index) {
        return dfdx(*this, index);
  }
```

then I call it in this way :

```
rhs.dfdx[j](t , uOld) )
```

but I got an error :

```
BackwardEulerSolver.H:114:50: error: invalid use of ‘class mg::numeric::odesystem::rhsODEProblem<double>::dfdx’
                                  ( 1- dt() * rhs.dfdx[j](t , uOld) ) ;
                                              ~~~~^~~~
```

Comment: This seems like an XY problem.   Why do you want to use `dfdt[index]( t , u_valarray )` instead of `dfdt(index, t, u_valarray )`??    In any event, the solution would be to eliminate the `dfdt()` member function, and create an object named `dfdt` that implements an `operator[]()` that returns a function object that accepts two arguments.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to change the method dfdt in a way in which I can call it using the following syntax **`dfdt[index]( t , u_valarray )`** instead of `dfdt(index, t, u_valarray )` In which way I can change this method ?

You can do that overloading the index operator (`[]`) and return an internal helper type, which overloads the call operator (`()`).

Here's a sketch:

```
 class foo {
     class foo_helper;
     friend class foo_helper;
 public:
     class foo_helper {
     public:
          foo_helper(foo &, int index);
          void operator()(int n, double y);
     };
     foo_helper operator[](int index) {
           return foo_helper(*this, index);
     }
 };
```

Comment: You're missing the fact that `dfdt()` in the question is a member function, not an instance of a class that can have an `operator[]()`.

Comment: @Peter And there's no way to call this member function with such construct I proposed?